# Spring Webflux. Webclient proxy authentication and endpoint ssl

Tags: spring-webflux

I'm testing webclient with an ssl service through proxy connection but I get the following error with the secure ssl connection.

Do you know what the problem is?

**Stack Trace:**

> {"timestamp":"2019-10-29T18:35:43.534+0000","path":"/football/areas","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","**message":"failure when writing TLS control frames","requestId":"abfc15e
>   8","trace":"javax.net.ssl.SSLException: failure when writing TLS control frame**s\r\n\tat io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailureTransportFailure(SslHandler.java:1807)\r\n\tSup
>   pressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: \nError has been observed at the following site(s):\n\t|_ checkpoint Ôçó Request to GET https://api.football-data.org/
>   v2/areas [DefaultWebClient]\n\t|_ checkpoint Ôçó Handler com.jpc.controller.ResillenceController#getAreas() [DispatcherHandler]\n\t|_ checkpoint Ôçó HTTP GET \"/football/areas\" [Excepti
>   onHandlingWebHandler]\nStack trace:\r\n\t\tat io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailureTransportFailure(SslHandler.java:1807)\r\n\t\tat io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.access$6
>   00(SslHandler.java:165)\r\n\t\tat io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$2.operationComplete(SslHandler.java:942)\r\n\t\tat io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$2.operationComplete(SslHandler.java:9
>   37)\r\n\t\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577)\r\n\t\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:55
>   1)\r\n\t\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490)\r\n\t\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615)\r\n\t\t
>   at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:608)\r\n\t\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117)\r\n\t\tat io.netty.c
>   hannel.PendingWriteQueue.safeFail(PendingWriteQueue.java:285)\r\n\t\tat io.netty.channel.PendingWriteQueue.removeAndFailAll(PendingWriteQueue.java:181)\r\n\t\tat io.netty.handler.proxy.P
>   roxyHandler.failPendingWrites(ProxyHandler.java:437)\r\n\t\tat io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyHandler.failPendingWritesAndClose(ProxyHandler.java:354)\r\n\t\tat io.netty.handler.proxy.Proxy
>   Handler.setConnectFailure(ProxyHandler.java:349)\r\n\t\tat io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyHandler.channelRead(ProxyHandler.java:269)\r\n\t\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext
>   .invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)\r\n\t\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)\r\n\t\tat io
>   .netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)\r\n\t\tat io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerConte
>   xt.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438)\r\n\t\tat io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:328)\r\n\t\tat io.netty.handler.

**Webclient Code**

```
public AreaServiceImpl(){

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(sslContextSpec -> {
        try {
            sslContextSpec.sslContext(SslContextBuilder
                    .forClient()
                    .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
                    .build());
        } catch (SSLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    })
            .tcpConfiguration(tcpClient -> {
                return tcpClient.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,8000)
                        .proxy(typeSpec -> {
                            typeSpec
                                    .type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP)
                                    .host("proxy")
                                    .port(port)
                                    .username("user")
                                    .password(s -> "password").build();

                        });

            });


    ReactorClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);

    //this.webClient = WebClient.create("https://api.football-data.org").;

    this.webClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(connector).baseUrl("https://api.football-data.org").build();
}
```

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: While not really a solution, I ran into the same error when the proxy server simply wasn't reachable from the requesting computer, while using a proxy load balancer (HAProxy) in between.